# Debug ASP.NET Core on Docker in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

So I've seen quite a few guides on the web on how to do this, but none of them seem to work with recent versions of the different tools.

So I start a fresh asp.net core 1.1.0 project and this is what I want to run and debug in docker.

Can anyone take me through the steps required to run and debug this in docker?